# Moving lots (1million+) files from one server to another - 'too many arguments'

Tags: ubuntu, gzip, rsync, tar, scp

I need to move lots of files from one server to another. All the files are images and fairly small but in total they are 10GB+.

I have attempted to use tar and gzip, but this fails because of 'too many arguments'.

How can I get around the 'too many arguments' issue?

Is there another way perhaps - could SCP or rsync do this?

Both boxes are Ubuntu.

**Edit**

The following seems to just hang and nothing happens, the images.tar.gz file is of size zero after the command is quit.

```
tar -zcvf images.tar.gz images
```

Comment: Your using * you should look into -r instead. * expands to all the files

Comment: You need to post the command line you are using. Have you just used a glob as above? Where are the filenames coming from?

Comment: Yes, definitely rsync.  Even if you got it all tarred up, if the 10 GB transfer gets messed up in the middle, you'd need to start all over again.  rsync will automatically retry, and is easy to restart.  Since the files are images, they are already compressed, and will not benefit from further compression.  I'd recommend using rsync directly on the files.

Comment: @Mark: true, `rsync` is better when files already exist, particularly if some have changed. However sending an archive is much faster for a one off transfer, especially if it contains a large number of files. If it fails, rsync can always be used after that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`-T -` will read the file names from stdin.  So you can do something like:

```
find . -name \*.jpg -print0 | tar -zcvf images.tar.gz --null -T -
```

However I would recommend rsync instead, as I noted in the comments.

As noted in the comments, the `print0` uses nulls ('\0') to terminate file names and `--null` for tar to use that, in order to accept more general file names with spaces and other terminators.

Comment: Better to use `print0` and the `--null` option with `tar`, this will handle any filename.

Comment: I am trying this, rsync not an easy option as I require VPN (which is slow) to ssh. This is just hanging so far for a long time - perhaps building the files list?

Comment: Let it do its thing.  Either that, or run it on a much smaller portion so that you can see how long it takes and build your confidence in its operation.

Comment: Is there a way I can farm it off to a background process, so if the pipe to the VPN dies it still runs? I can then reconnect and check the file size to see if its finished?

Comment: That is one of the huge advantages to using rsync.  If the process or connection is interrupted, you can simply restart rsync, and it will figure out on its own what made it and what didn't, and pick up right where it left off.

Comment: @Mark-Adler you have been a star, one more question, could I do this by the date the files were added - e.g. only tar files added in the last 6 months?

Comment: Found it `-ctime -100` for upto 100 days in the past

Answer (score 1):

Try `cpio`, it reads the list of files from `stdin`. You can pipe the output through `ssh`:

```
find images -print0 | cpio -o0x ustar | ssh user@host cpio -i
```

Or with compression

```
find images -print0 | cpio -o0x ustar | gzip | ssh user@host 'gunzip  | cpio -i'
```

#### Update

Actually this is answer won't work as GNU `cpio` only implements archive formats with limited size. Answer has been updated to use the `ustar` format, which is more than the 2 GiB limit of the default one, but still is only 8 GiB. Mark Addler's `tar` answer is probably the best way to go for larger amounts of data.